# Which sentences are irreducibly self-referential?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, peano-axioms, incompleteness

*Below, all sentences/formulas are in the language of arithmetic, and for simplicity we conflate numbers with numerals and sentences with Godel numbers.*

*Now asked [at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/417499/8133).*

---

Say that a sentence $\varphi$ is **irreducibly self-referential** iff there is a formula $\chi(x)$ such that the following are equivalent for all sentences $\psi$:

1. $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$.
2. $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\psi\leftrightarrow\chi({\psi})$.
3. $\mathsf{PA}\vdash \chi({\psi})\leftrightarrow\varphi$.

*(Note that the 1/2 equivalence implies that $\mathsf{PA}\vdash \varphi\leftrightarrow\chi(\varphi)$. Also, this isn't a typo: I really do want to require an "equivalence of provable equivalences" here.)*

Intuitively, the 1/2-equivalence asserts that when we interpret $\varphi$ as saying "I have property $\chi$," we don't lose any information about $\varphi$: any two ways of whipping up such a sentence result in the same meaning. The 2/3-equivalence is a bit weirder. It says that we can't remove the self-referential aspect of $\varphi$ by shifting the referent to $\psi$: if $\varphi$ could be rephrased as "$\psi$ has property $\chi$," then $\psi$ already involves the same type of self-reference as $\varphi$.

Basically, if $\varphi$ is irreducibly self-referential via $\chi$, then (modulo a special consideration for the role of $\mathsf{PA}$) reading $\varphi$ as "I have property $\chi$" is both appropriate and optimal.

My question is simply:

> Is there a snappy description of the irreducibly self-referential sentences?

It's consistent with my understanding so far that every sentence is irreducibly self-referential, *or* that only the decidable sentences are irreducibly self-referential. Obviously each of these outcomes would be a bit boring; my hope is that i.s.r. actually provides a nontrivial dividing line amongst the independent sentences, but I have no evidence for that at the moment. (And in fact, the way these things tend to go I do suspect that one or the other of the "boring" outcomes holds for simple reasons, I just don't see the argument yet.)

---

Here are a couple easy observations:

- **Silly examples**: Via $\mathsf{Prov}_{\mathsf{PA}}(-)$ (and Lob's Theorem), every $\mathsf{PA}$-theorem is irreducibly self-referential. A related argument via non-disprovability gives the i.s.r.-ness of every $\mathsf{PA}$-disprovable sentence.
- **Non-example**: Let $\chi=\neg\mathsf{Prov}_{\mathsf{PA}}$ be the usual unprovability predicate for $\mathsf{PA}$, and let $\varphi$ be a fixed point for that predicate. It is [known](http://jdh.hamkins.org/are-all-godel-sentences-equivalent/) that any two fixed points of $\neg\mathsf{Prov}_\mathsf{PA}$ are $\mathsf{PA}$-provably equivalent, so $\varphi$ satisfies the 1/2-equivalence. However, taking $\psi=\perp$ we see that $\varphi$ **fails** to satisfy the 1/3-equivalence: $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\neg\mathsf{Prov_{PA}}(\perp)\leftrightarrow\varphi$ is true (indeed this is how we establish the 1/2 equivalence for $\varphi$) but $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\perp\leftrightarrow\varphi$ is (hopefully!) not. So the usual Godel sentence is not irreducibly self-referential via $\neg\mathsf{Prov}_{\mathsf{PA}}$ ... although in principle it could be irreducibly self-referential via some other formula.

Comment: Suppose that $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma_{n}$-formula. This may be completely unhelpful, but my first instinct would be to consider the partial truth predicate for $\Sigma_{n}$-formulas $\mathrm{Tr}_{n}$ and take $\chi(x)$ to be $\varphi \wedge \mathrm{Tr}_{n}(x)$. Does that yield anything interesting, at least if we restrict the range of $\psi$ to $\Sigma_{n}$-formulas?

Comment: @Pilcrow Contra my earlier (and now-deleted) comment, I think that doesn't work even when we restrict to $\Sigma_n$: if we take for example $\psi=\top$, then condition 3 is satisfied since $\varphi\wedge\top\equiv\varphi$ but condition 1 won't be in general.